# python - How to concatenate consecutive rows without losing the order of the records in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two rows based on a categorical variable when the categories of the variable in the consecutive rows are same. Here is my data below for example :

```
   SNo  user    Text
0   1   Sam     Hello
1   1   John    Hi
2   1   Sam     How are you?
3   1   John    I am good
4   1   John    How about you?
5   1   John    How is it going?
6   1   Sam     Its going good
7   1   Sam     Thanks
8   2   Mary    Howdy?
9   2   Jake    Hey!!
10  2   Jake    What a surprise
11  2   Mary    Good to see you here :)
12  2   Jake    Ha ha. Hectic life
13  2   Mary    I know right..
14  2   Mary    How's Amy doing?
15  2   Mary    How are the kids?
16  2   Jake    All is good! :)
```

Here, if my previous value of `user` column is same as my current value of `user` column but different from the next value in that column, then, I'd concatenate the values from the column `Text` for that user. I need to do this until there are no more multiple occurrence of that particular user. A sample output is given below :

```
SNo user    Text
1   Sam     Hello
1   John    Hi
1   Sam     How are you?
1   John    I am good-How about you?-How is it going?
1   Sam     Its going good-Thanks
2   Mary    Howdy?
2   Jake    Hey!!-What a surprise
2   Mary    Good to see you here :)
2   Jake    Ha ha. Hectic life
2   Mary    I know right..-How's Amy doing?-How are the kids?
2   Jake    All is good! :)
```

I tried using `df.groupby()` and then `.agg()` to get the concatenation done but unable to apply the above mentioned condition over it. Hence the output is combining all occurrences of an user for a chat.

```
df = sample_data.groupby(["SNo","user"]).agg({'Text': '-'.join}).reset_index() # incorrect though
df
```

Moreover, I am trying to avoid `for` loop like a plague and trying out a vectorised solution.

---

Sample data  :

```
data_dict = {'S. No.': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'user': ['Sam', 'John', 'Sam', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Mary', 'Jake', 'Jake', 'Mary', 'Jake ', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Jake'], 'Text': ['Hello', 'Hi', 'How are you?', 'I am good', 'How about you?', 'How is it going?', 'Its going good', 'Thanks', 'Howdy?', 'Hey!!', 'What a surprise', 'Good to see you here :)', 'Ha ha. Hectic life', 'I know right..', "How's Amy doing?", 'How are the kids?', 'All is good! :)']}

sample_data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to compare `user` with its `shift` and `cumsum` for changes. Then you can groupby:

```
blocks = df['user'].ne(df['user'].shift()).cumsum()
(df.groupby(['SNo', blocks])
  .agg({'user':'first','Text': '-'.join})
  .reset_index('user', drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
     user                                               Text
SNo                                                         
1     Sam                                              Hello
1    John                                                 Hi
1     Sam                                       How are you?
1    John          I am good-How about you?-How is it going?
1     Sam                              Its going good-Thanks
2    Mary                                             Howdy?
2    Jake                              Hey!!-What a surprise
2    Mary                            Good to see you here :)
2    Jake                                 Ha ha. Hectic life
2    Mary  I know right..-How's Amy doing?-How are the kids?
2    Jake                                    All is good! :)
```

Comment: Seeing `.shift()` attribute for the first time ever!

Comment: I have a similar problem but I have to combine the text of at least 40 columns just like you have done for one column named 'Text'. How can I do that? I have tried the above solution but it can work for a single column.